# How do i get listview's child?

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I want to change text in textview which is in a listview on click

```
listViewMessage = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);      
listViewMessage.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
     txtViewMess = (TextView) listViewMessage.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage); //error
     txtViewMess.setText("Paid");
    }
    });
```

Code worked for a couple of textview, but some turned to

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: check rootview and listViewMessage one of this may be  null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `callback` in your code .

**YourAdapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    ...
    viewHolder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTextClickListener.onTextClick(i);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

/**
 * text click
 */
public interface onItemTextClickListener {
    void onTextClick(int i);
}

private onItemTextClickListener mTextClickListener;

public void setOnItemTextClickListener(onItemTextClickListener mTextClickListener) {
    this.mTextClickListener = mTextClickListener;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView mTextView;
}
```

**Call method**

```
mAdapter.setOnItemTextClickListener(new onItemTextClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTextClick(int i) {
            // do something here
        }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work, but I tried     txtViewMess = (TextView) listViewMessage.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage); to     view.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage); and it's worked perfectly

Comment: Good luck to you.

Comment: You can check my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

just get it like this

```
TextView tv=adapterView.getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.my_tv);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong view to initialize your text view:

```
listViewMessage = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);      
listViewMessage.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int 
position, long id) {
txtViewMess = (TextView) 
view.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage); //error
txtViewMess.setText("Paid");
}
});
```

Comment: This will work. Dont forget to mark this post as answer if it works as it will help others in future too.Happy Coding :)